# Remove phantom files from Perforce changelist?

Tags: perforce

P4 keeps wanting to commit some files that don't exist on disk:

`open for read: <Path to non-existent-file>: The system cannot find the path specified.`

Any idea how I can get P4 to forget about them?

Comment: Have those files been added manually to the change list or how did they make it on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit your changelist and remove the phantom files.  If they are in the default changelist, run

```
p4 change
```

from the command line and it will bring up an editor; remove the files you don't want from the Files: section and save.  On saving, Perforce will create a new changelist which you can submit with:

```
p4 submit -c <changelist number>
```

You should also revert the missing files so that they don't continue to appear in your default changelist:

```
p4 revert <path to files>
```

Comment: Might also need to 'p4 revert' those phantom files afterwards, so they don't just sit around opened, and clog up the next changelist.